# Django: Call self function inside a Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to call for a self function of a model class as such in upload_to:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    filestack = models.FileField(upload_to=self. gen_save_path)

    def gen_save_path(self):
        """
        gen_save_path: void -> String
        Generates the path as a string for fileStack field.
        """
        return "some generated string"
```

However I am getting `NameError: name 'self' is not defined` error

Answer (score 5):

`filestack` is a class attribute and while declaring it you can not use self as there is no object of class (`self`) yet created, anyway according to django [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) `upload_to` takes two arguments, instance (An instance of the model where the FileField is defined) and filename (The filename that was originally given to the file), so you can set `upload_to` to such function

```
def gen_save_path(instance, filename):
    """
    gen_save_path: void -> String
    Generates the path as a string for fileStack field.
    """
    return "some generated string"

class Foo(models.Model):

    filestack = models.FileField(upload_to=gen_save_path)
```

If you wish to include `gen_save_path` inside the class, you can use a lambda to call `self.gen_save_path` e.g.

```
class Foo(models.Model):

    filestack = models.FileField(upload_to=lambda self, fname:self.gen_save_path(fname))

    def gen_save_path(self, filename):
        return "some generated string"
```

Answer (score -2):

I think this will work if you use a lambda function:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    filestack = models.FileField(upload_to=lambda: self.gen_save_path())

    def gen_save_path(self):
        """
        gen_save_path: void -> String
        Generates the path as a string for fileStack field.
        """
        return "some generated string"
```

Comment: you cannot use `self` in an attribute definition. `undefined name: self`

Answer (score -2):

in your code, the filestack is a class wide scope variable since not defined in a method.
so there is no available self in this scope.

i think you can use :

```
filestack =models.FileField(upload_to=Foo.gen_save_path)
```

or

define filestack value within a `__init__` constructor, where you can use self !!

Comment: I think the last solution is the best one, define everything that is not class specific in the __init__ constructor

Comment: I like the first method here, but you will need to define `gen_save_path` as a classmethod if you do that.

Comment: You can NOT access class name inside the class, Foo.gen_save_path will give error `Foo` not defined