# call self method inside a django model fields for get choices

Tags: django, django-models

I want to call a self method from django model field for get choice options.

I search over stackoverflow as well as google and find some solution but these solution not working in my case. here is some of solution already exist. [Django: Call self function inside a Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091667/django-call-self-function-inside-a-django-model).

Here is my model :

```
MPL_CHOICE = (
    ("a", "assistance"),
    ("b", "Performed"),
    ("n", "Need assistance"),
    ("o", "Observed"),
)

class ProcedurName(models.Model):
    my_choices = models.CharField(
        "My Choices", 
        max_length=100, 
        null=False, 
        blank=False, 
        choices=self.mpl_choice_filed()
    )
    def mpl_choice_filed(self):
        if self.pk:
            avrage_acore = self.avrage_acore.all()
            MPL_CHOICE_NEW = [(m.value,m.label) for m in minimun_avrage_acore]
            return MPL_CHOICE_NEW
        else:
            return MPL_CHOICE


class ChoicesAfterEdited(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(
            "MinimunAvrageScore Lavel",
            max_length=250,
        )
    value = models.CharField(
            "MinimunAvrageScore Value",
            max_length=250,
        )
    procedure = models.ForeignKey(
        ProcedureSetup, 
        null=True, blank=True, 
        related_name='avrage_acore'
    )
```

If you see into model, in  my_choices field  I try to call self.mpl_choice_filed  method but I am getting this error.

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Please help me to find out solution.

Answer (score 1):

`self` is not available at the time of Model class definition.

Anyway you can not have different `choices` for different instances of `ProcedurName` model.  You should manipulate with the `choices` somewhere in the form handling.